# ListView choice mode

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me why when i set this property to my ListView:

```
mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

The items on the list seems to reload anytime I click on one of them? If i remove that property that behaviour doesn´t show up.

I'm setting this in the OnCreateView method of my activity, I could also set this up in my xml getting the same result:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="@string/per_lista"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:divider="#e2e2e2"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
```

Comment: when do you call this function?

Comment: Are you sure items are reloading?, because in a listView the view is reloading the whole time but not exactly the items, choiceMode no matters in this behavior. Just my opinion

Comment: @vgarzom yes the rows are reloading , every row in my ListView has an ImageView and when I click any row the ImageViews of all the visible rows are reloaded

Comment: Every time an item is checked/unchecked the `ListView` calls `requestLayout()` which causes its children to be redrawn. It doesn't mean the items are being reloaded, though. If your items are being reloaded then we'll need more information. Could you put up the code for your adapter and fragment/activity? Just in case you want to have a look, the `ListView` source can be found through this link http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setChoiceMode%28int%29

Comment: @ebarrenchea Yes it looks like the listview is redrawing the children is almost as if notifyDataSetChanged() was being called on the adapter. Do you know a way to avoid the list items to be redrawn?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know and I'm not even sure it's the intended behaviour since they items are being redrawn so that their selected state can be set or reset according to the selection. You could always use the source code as a basis for your own custom `ListView` that doesn't request a layout pass/redraw after its selection state changes.

Comment: Are you having problems with the redrawn? I say it because in an application that a I made, I had this problem: when ListView was redraw, some times the image view didn't load the correct drawable. The logic for selecting the image was in the Adapter class, what I did for correct the problem was to pass to the adapter an Object with the image and the text I needed to display. Maybe this can help you. BestRegards!

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys but I think ebarrenchea answer is the one that describes better my problem and explains it, @ebarrenchea  can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @BigBen3216 I've combined both comments into an answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time an item is checked/unchecked the ListView calls requestLayout() which causes its children to be redrawn. It doesn't mean the items are being reloaded, though. If your items are being reloaded then we'll need more information. Just in case you want to have a look, the ListView source can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setChoiceMode%28int%29).

Unfortunately I don't know and I'm not even sure you can avoid the list items being redrawn. It's the intended behaviour since the items are being redrawn so that their selected state can be set or reset according to the selection. You could always use the source code as a basis for your own custom ListView that doesn't request a layout pass/redraw after its selection state changes.